Facing build error in SItecore10.1 JSS NextJS Project with adding output: 'export' in next.config.js
Steps I have followed so far:

npm i -g @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli@18.0.0
jss create testapp nextjs --branch release/18.0.0
jss start
Add output:'export' in next.config.js file
npm run build - **This command throws the below error**


TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported
    at getNodeRequestOptions (C:\Repos\JSS\testapp-jss\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1305:9)
    at C:\Repos\JSS\testapp-jss\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1410:19
    at new Promise ()
    at fetch (C:\Repos\JSS\testapp-jss\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1407:9)
    at fetch (C:\Repos\JSS\testapp-jss\node_modules\cross-fetch\dist\node-ponyfill.js:10:20)
    at C:\Repos\JSS\testapp-jss\node_modules\graphql-request\dist\index.js:163:42
    at step (C:\Repos\JSS\testapp-jss\node_modules\graphql-request\dist\index.js:63:23)
    at Object.next (C:\Repos\JSS\testapp-jss\node_modules\graphql-request\dist\index.js:44:53)
    at C:\Repos\JSS\testapp-jss\node_modules\graphql-request\dist\index.js:38:71
    at new Promise () {
  type: 'TypeError'

Need help on this issue

Can you share your next-config.js file here

When you configure output: 'export', Next.js requires all URLs used in the project to be absolute. This is because static export doesn’t support relative URLs for API calls, as it expects all data to be fetched and available at build time. Double-check that any API calls or image paths are using absolute URLs.
